# Как развернуть таблицу по горизонтали запросом в firebird

Tags: строки, запрос, firebird, join, inner-join

Есть запрос:

```
select post.i, model.n, balans.y, balans.m, sum(balans.itog)
from balans
inner join post on (balans.pred=post.n)
inner join model on (post.model=model.i)
where ((balans.y=2015) and ((post.model='P') and (balans.itog)>0)))
group by post.i,model.n, balans.y, balans.m
```

Вывод помесячно идет во один столбец. Как можно сделать что бы каждый месяц из таблицы `balans.m=1 ... balans.m=12` выводился в отдельный столбец такого вида:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный прием - разворот CASE'ом:

```
select post.i, model.n, balans.y,
  SUM(CASE WHEN balans.m = 1 THEN balans.itog END) AS M1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN balans.m = 2 THEN balans.itog END) AS M2,
...
  SUM(CASE WHEN balans.m = 11 THEN balans.itog END) AS M11,
  SUM(CASE WHEN balans.m = 12 THEN balans.itog END) AS M12
from balans
inner join post on (balans.pred=post.n)
inner join model on (post.model=model.i)
where ((balans.y=2015) and ((post.model='P') and (balans.itog)>0)))
group by post.i,model.n, balans.y
```